# Passing an array of objects to child component in ReactJS but the first return it's undefined and breaks the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a personal blog for my brand and the Posts section works by fetching data from a basic `JSON` with an API, mocked with mirageJS for now, and using the `useEffect` and `useState` hooks i'm setting data for the `<PostComponent />` who are displayed on screen using a `array.map()` function.The problem is:

- If i want to set the array to a State hook inside the child component i get an error because the first return it's 'undefined' despite the fact the second return it's the correct JSON.

PostsPage.js **//Parent//**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import PostComponent from './Post';
import { Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';

import '../MenuBar/MenuBar.css';
import '../../assets/Global.css'


function HomePage() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]); //array of objects of the post's content
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false); //If it's false, display 'loading' icon
  
  //Fetching data from the API
  useEffect(() => {
    
    fetch(`/api/posts`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setPost(data.posts);
      setIsLoaded(true);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });      

}, []);
console.log(post); //checking the return
function SpinnerIcon(){ //'Loading' icon
  return(
  <div className="menu-bar">
     <div className="menu-aligner">
       <div className="spinner-box">
        <Spinner 
            className="load-animation" 
            animation="border" 
            variant="info" />
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  )
}

function PostsList() {//Posts 
  return(
    <div className="menu-bar">
      <div className="menu-aligner">
        {
          post.map(item => (
            <PostComponent infos={item} key={item.id} />
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function HandleChange(props){
  if(props.props === false){
    return <SpinnerIcon />
  } else {
    return <PostsList />
  }
}


  return (
    <HandleChange props={isLoaded}/>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Post.js **//Child//**

```
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

import square from '../../assets/img/square.png';

function PostComponent(infos) {
  console.log(infos.infos); //checking the received data
    return(
      <article className="article-box">
        <Row>
         <Col xs={3}>
          <img className="article-img" src={square} alt="imagem" />
         </Col>

         <Col xs={7} className="inside-text" >
           <h3>{infos.infos.name}</h3>
           {<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:[infos.infos.descrip]}}></span>}
           <br/>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={10}>
             <button>Ler Mais</button>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={1} className="date-post">
             <small>{infos.infos.date}</small>
            </Col>
          </Row> 
         </Col>
        </Row> 
      </article>
    )
}

export default PostComponent;
```

I'm wondering if have a possibility of the first return don't be undefined or what would be a good practice on that situation.

Comment: I'm setting the array fetched from the API inside the "post" hook and passing it to the Child through the info property. Inside the Child, making a console.log(info)  the first return will be "undefined" and the code breaks.

Comment: Easiest way of solving this would be to add an undefined check on your rendering logic, such as by changing `post.map(item => (<PostComponent infos={item} key=item.id} />))` to `post && post.map(item => (<PostComponent infos={item} key=item.id} />))`

Comment: `const [post, setPost] = useState([]);` you are starting off with an empty `array`, not `undefined`.  So on the first render you should just be mapping an empty array which is not a problem.  Are you sure it's not `data.posts` that's `undefined`?  Also you should define other components like `SpinnerIcon` **outside** of the `HomePage` component.  It's not good to define a component inside of another because it means that the component gets redefined on every render and gets unmounted and remounted rather than just updating its props.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem `infos.infos.name`

You have two ways you can fix this

1.
you can either do  `infos && infos.infos.name`. This will only show if infos is not a falsy value.

2.
You can use the `infos?.infos?.name`

Since you are mapping over `post` then your post is an array so you should not have this problem. if you have an empty array it will map over nothing. If you have items in your array then it will map over your `PostComponent`

You have left out a bit of code for us the be able to understand this correctly.